# Using Google Cloud Identity and planning migrating to G Suite

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We are currently using Google Cloud Platform for some of our core products. The users have been registering their company email addresses, which is hosted with a different provider, as Google Accounts in order to connect to the GCP services.

We are now looking at using Google Cloud Identity instead to manage accounts. However there is a plan to eventually move the entire business to G Suite.

Will it be possible to use Cloud Identity at the moment and still seamlessly move all of those account created over to G Suite when we eventually move the company email etc?

Comment: This question does not seem to be related to a programming problem, so it might not be appropriate here.

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Platform and G-Suite are effectively essentially use the same underlying user system. Cloud Identity has 2 tiers, free and premium, and you're already using the free tier when you create users with either GCP or G-Suite.

So yes, your user accounts accounts now are just Cloud Identity accounts accessing GCP, but you can easily add G-Suite licenses to them (all or just some) and they'll get access to gmail and apps automatically.

You can also add Cloud Identity Premium when you have even more complex user management scenarios, although that doesn't seem to be the case from your description.